# Calculate the number of items PHP

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, rss

For some reason I want to use a for loop, not a foreach, so how do I can get the length of $item? count() doesn't work for me.

```
$xml = "http://www.labnol.org/feed/";

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

            var_dump(count($x->item(0)));

  for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
}
```

Comment: why are you dumping item 0 instead of pure $x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `->lenth`, you should do this

```
var_dump($x->length);
```

Comment: not working, i got Notice: Undefined property: DOMElement::$length

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');` is a `DOMNodeList` and has a `$length` property.

```
var_dump($x->length);
```

Will return the length of the node list.

Node lists implement `Traversable`, too. So they can be used with foreach.

```
foreach ($x as $item) { 
  //...
}
```

However, XPath is more flexible than the DOM methods. You can fetch the item count or the first 6 `item` nodes.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(//item)'));

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item[position() <= 5]') as $item) {
  ...
}
```